# Minimize doesn't work

Tags: mathematical-optimization, output

I'm trying to minimize the function V(phi) using the code below

```
f =.
th =.
mu =.
md =.
V[phi_] := -2 * (mu Cos[phi + th/2] + md Cos[phi - th/2])
Minimize[V[phi], phi]
```

But the output is just the command itself!

```
Out: Minimize[-2 (md Cos[phi - th/2] + mu Cos[phi + th/2]), phi]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you give it numerical values for `th,md,mu` then it can do it. I guess it is too hard to do for general case and without any constraints.

Comment: Since I don't immediately see any denominators, what about `Reduce[D[V[phi],phi]==0&&D[V[phi],{phi,2}]>0,phi]` but that takes long enough that the final result may be too complicated to be useful.

Comment: @Nasser Right. How do I add them? They are simple stuff: th,md,mu>0. I tried with `$Assumptions =  th >= 0 && mu >= 0 && md >= 0`, but without much success.

Comment: When I tried it, it only solved it when giving exact values for `th,md,mu`. It did not work using range on these like you showed. These have to be given some numerical values before calling `Minimize`.  May be someone else will have better ideas.

Comment: `Minimize` does not use the option `Assumptions`; consequently, `$Assumptions` has no affect on it. Include the assumptions as constraints inside the `Minimize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

V[phi_] := -2*(mu  Cos[phi + th/2] + md  Cos[phi - th/2])
```

I have set some arbitrary constraints to reduce the complexity of the result.

```
cond = Assuming[{mu > 0, md > 0, 0 < th < 2 Pi, 0 < phi < 2 Pi},
  Reduce[{D[V[phi], phi] == 0, D[V[phi], {phi, 2}] > 0, mu > 0, md > 0, 
     0 < th < 2 Pi, 0 < phi < 2 Pi}, phi] // FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Since the `Head` of `cond` is `Or`, it can be turned into a `Piecewise` expression:

```
min = Piecewise[{Simplify[V[phi], #], #} & /@ (List @@ cond)]
```

[image]